# QFontMetrics Width using PySide6

Tags: qt, pyqt5, pyside, pyside6

I have the following line in my code:

```
self.textLength = self.fontMetrics().width(self.text())
```

It works with PyQt5, but I'm trying to move the code to PySide6, and when I do I get the error `AttributeError: type object 'PySide6.QtGui.QFontMetrics' has no attribute 'width'`

I've tried reading through the QFontMetrics docs, but everything I do seems to give the same error. Any ideas of how I can convert this line to PySide6? Thank you!

Comment: You said that you've tried reading through the QFontMetrics. Do you see `width()` in the documentation? It has been considered obsolete even in Qt 5 (since 5.11), and there's no trace of it in Qt6 docs (nor C++ or Python).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`QFontMetrics.width()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics-obsolete.html#width) has been considered obsolete since Qt 5.5 and deprecated from Qt 5.11 (but will probably be still supported throughout any future releases of Qt 5), and eventually removed in Qt 6.

As the documentation (which already is in the obsolete members page of Qt5) reports, the results of `width()` were inconsistent and unreliable in many situations, mostly because it didn't consider the letter *bearings*.

You should use [`horizontalAdvance()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#horizontalAdvance) or [`boundingRect()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#boundingRect)`.width()`.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like I had pulled up older docs for PyQt4 and an old version of PySide. I used horizontalAdvance() and it worked as it should. Thanks again!